# Iterate through a range

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator

I need to iterate from `1` up to a given number `A`. I have achieved this using the following code:

```
(1..A).step(1) do |n| puts n end
```

Is there any better method than this?

My default step will be 1.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: Just trying to refactor to see for better options

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should belong to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you just want to _print_ the numbers: `puts *1..A`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case more idiomatic [arguably] way would be to use [`Integer#upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-upto):

```
1.upto(A) { |n| puts n }
```

Also, `step(1)` is a default one and you might simply iterate the range itself:

```
(1..A).each { |n| puts n }
```

Or, even using [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-times):

```
A.times { |n| puts n + 1 }
```

Note, that `Integer#times` starts counting from `0` hence `+ 1` is required.

**NB** please also note the very valuable comment by @Stefan below.

Comment: It might be worth noting that—although they produce the same output—each solution has a different return value: `1`, `1..A` and `A` respectively. (because they all return the receiver)